# Are there any issues when using Konva on iOS mobile devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, canvas, next.js, konvajs

I am using a Konva stage to hover over floor areas on browser (see running Next app here https://www.planpoint.io/themes/modern-1) and it works great on any device, except on iPhones. After some touches on the floors areas, they suddenly dissapear as if the canvas element would no longer be there. Has tested it with Safari and Chrome on iOS16.2 . The only difference for mobile devices is the use of touchstart, touchend events, instead of mouseover, mouseout events.

Here is the code for rendering the canvas component and background image

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

import Image from 'next/image'

import Konva from 'konva';

import i18nService from '../../../helpers/i18nService'

import useWindowSize from '../../../hooks/useWindowSize'

export default function InteractiveCanvas(props) {
  const [showCanvas, setShowCanvas] = useState(false);

  const [placeholderWidth, setPlaceholderWidth] = useState(1);
  const [placeholderHeight, setPlaceholderHeight] = useState(1);

  const [width, height] = useWindowSize();

  const canvasAreaRef = useRef(null)
  const canvasPlaceholderRef = useRef()

  let stage, shapesLayer, tooltipLayer;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showCanvas) {
      props.loaded() // Canvas has loaded
    }
  },[showCanvas])

  useLayoutEffect(() => { initializeCanvas() });

  useEffect(() => { initializeCanvas() }, [width, height]);

  function initializeCanvas() {
    if (!canvasPlaceholderRef.current || !canvasPlaceholderRef.current.clientWidth || !canvasPlaceholderRef.current.clientHeight || !canvasPlaceholderRef.current.clientWidth) {
      // wait until the placeholder is available
      setTimeout(function() { initializeCanvas() }, 1000)
    } else if (canvasPlaceholderRef.current) {
      // initialize placeholder
      setPlaceholderWidth(canvasAreaRef.current.clientWidth)
      setPlaceholderHeight(canvasPlaceholderRef.current.clientHeight)

      // initialize konva
      let width = canvasPlaceholderRef.current.clientWidth;
      let height = canvasPlaceholderRef.current.clientHeight;

      stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: props.konvaContainer,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        name: 'stage'
      });

      shapesLayer = new Konva.Layer({ name: 'shapes' });
      tooltipLayer = new Konva.Layer({ name: 'tooltips' });

      let tooltip = new Konva.Label({
        opacity: 1,
        visible: false,
        listening: false,
        name: 'label'
      });

      tooltip.add(
        new Konva.Tag({
          fill: '#313131',
          pointerDirection: 'down',
          pointerWidth: 20,
          pointerHeight: 10,
          cornerRadius: 4,
          lineJoin: 'round',
          shadowColor: 'black',
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowOffsetX: 10,
          shadowOffsetY: 10,
          shadowOpacity: 0.25,
          name: 'tag'
        })
      );

      tooltip.add(
        new Konva.Text({
          text: '',
          align: 'center',
          lineHeight: 2,
          fontFamily: 'Inter',
          fontSize: 13,
          padding: 5,
          fill: 'white',
          name: 'tag',
          width: props.wideTooltip ? 160 : 80
        })
      );

      tooltipLayer.add(tooltip);

      let areas = getData();

      // draw areas
      for (let key in areas) {
        let area = areas[key];

        let shape = new Konva.Line({
          stroke: 'white',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          points: area.points,
          fill: area.color,
          opacity: area.disabled || area.visible ? 1 : key === props.selected?.name ? 1 : 0, // Keep the selected floor/unit highlight shape with opacity 1 after render
          disabled: area.disabled,
          closed: true,
          target: area.target,
          key: key,
          subline: area.subline,
          perfectDrawEnabled: false,
          name: 'line',
          cursor: 'pointer'
        });

        let group = new Konva.Group({name: 'group'})

        shapesLayer.add(group);
        group.add(shape);
      }

      stage.add(shapesLayer);
      stage.add(tooltipLayer);

      stage.on('mouseover touchstart', function (evt) {
        if (evt && evt.target) {
          let shape = evt.target;
          if (shape && !shape.attrs.editable) {
            shape.opacity(1);
            shapesLayer.draw();
            if (evt.type === 'touchstart' && shape.attrs.name === 'line') props.onClick(shape.attrs.target)
          }
        }
      });

      stage.on('mouseout touchend', function (evt) {
        if (evt && evt.target) {
          let shape = evt.target;
          if(shape.attrs.name === 'stage' || shape.attrs.target === props.selected?._id) return // Do nothing unless it  is a different line shape

          if (shape && !shape.attrs.editable) {
            shape.opacity(shape.attrs.disabled || shape.attrs.visible ? 1 : 0);
            shapesLayer.draw();
            tooltip.hide();
            tooltipLayer.draw();
          }
        }
      });

      stage.on('mousemove', function(evt) {
        let shape = evt.target;
        if (shape) {
          let mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
          let x = mousePos.x;
          let y = mousePos.y - 5;
          updateTooltip(tooltip, x, y, shape.attrs.key, shape.attrs.subline);
          tooltipLayer.draw();
        }
      });

      stage.on('click tap', function(evt) {
        let shape = evt.target;
        if(shape.attrs.name === 'stage' || shape.attrs.target === props.selected?._id) return // Do nothing unless it  is a different line shape
        if (shape && shape.attrs.target) props.onClick(shape.attrs.target)
      })

      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowCanvas(true)

        shapesLayer.draw();
        tooltipLayer.draw();
      }, 100)
    }
  }

  function getData() {
    let areas = {}

    function transformPoints(points) {
      const c = JSON.parse(points || '[]')
      return c.map((e, i) => (i % 2) ? (placeholderWidth * e) : placeholderHeight * e)
    }

    // add inactive paths
    for (let p of props.inactivePaths) {
      let newData = {
        target: p.target,
        color: p.disabled ? (props.disabledColor || '#E1171799') : props.accentColor || 'rgba(15, 33, 49, 0.65)',
        points: transformPoints(p.path),
        visible: p.visible,
        disabled: p.disabled
      }

      if (props.project && props.project.showFloorOverview) {
        let availableUnits = p.units.filter(u => u.availability.toLowerCase() === 'available').length
        newData.subline = props.project.showFloorOverview ? `${availableUnits} ${i18nService.i18n(props.locale, "canvas.unitsavailable")}` : ''
      }

      areas[p.title] = newData
    }

    return areas;
  }

  function updateTooltip(tooltip, x, y, text, subline) {
    const conditionalSubline = subline ? `\n${subline}` : ''

    tooltip.children[1].text(text+conditionalSubline);
    // tooltip.getText().text(text);
    tooltip.position({ x: x, y: y });
    if (text) tooltip.show();
  };

  return (
    <div className={props.styles.canvasContainer}>
      <img
        className={props.styles.canvasImgPlaceholder}
        ref={canvasPlaceholderRef}
        alt='Canvas Placeholder'
        src={props.background}
        />

      <div className={props.styles.canvasPlaceholderBox} data-hide={showCanvas}>
        <Image src="/images/planpoint_icon.svg" width={200} height={200} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div
        className={props.styles.canvasKonvaContainer}
        id={props.konvaContainer}
        ref={canvasAreaRef}
        data-hide={!showCanvas}
        style={{backgroundImage: `url('${props.background}')`}}
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do some research around generic canvas on safari - I think there were some issues but there are workarounds. Sorry cant recall specific links.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I have detected that issue on Safari and Chrome, that is why I suspect it's got something to do with iOS. Thank you for the suggestion!